# swift - why global static variable is not init?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

### Problem

- Sometimes (maybe thread) `kIndexMinID`, `kIndexMaxID` value is `0`

### Code

```
// test.swift
let kIndexMinID :Int    = 100
let kIndexMaxID :Int    = 200
```

### Question

- Why not init value? (when init?)
- How to global variable init ?

### Status

- Xcode 8.2.1
- Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Even in different threads, no way you can get value as `0`. Could you provide a testable example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's highly recommended to encapsulate constants in structs

```
struct Constants {
   static let kIndexMinID = 100
   static let kIndexMaxID = 200
}
```

The benefit (apart from the encapsulation) is that the constants are initialized lazily.

Comment: thank`s. case my situation is **struct** member is init value success

Comment: According to https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html, *“Global constants and variables are always computed lazily”*

Comment: Sorry, but I don't  see how this answers the question (which itself is unclear). Encapsulation is a good advice, but (unless I am mistaken) it makes no difference with respect to the (lazy) initialization.